# How to configure tomee to run over https?

Tags: java, apache, maven, tomcat, pom.xml

I am trying to configure a web application to run on https using tomee maven plugin, but it defaults to http. How can I specify the necessary config to use https?

This is what I did so far:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.openejb.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomee-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <tomeeVersion>1.7.1</tomeeVersion>
                    <tomeeClassifier>plus</tomeeClassifier>
                    <tomeeHttpsPort>8443</tomeeHttpsPort>
                    <context>${artifactId}</context>
                    <tomeeHost>testapp</tomeeHost>
                    <systemVariables>
                        <javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword>changeit</javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword>
                        <javax.net.ssl.keystoreFile>keystorePath</javax.net.ssl.keystoreFile>
                    </systemVariables>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 1):

As I see by checking the version of the plugin, the feature to use https by default isn't implemented.

You could use version 7.0.3 instead:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomee.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomee-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm not entirely sure, if it's the same plugin just with another groupId, but the [github where the plugin is developed](https://github.com/apache/tomee/blob/master/maven/tomee-maven-plugin) looks promising.

So as stated in [this mailing-list](http://tomee-openejb.979440.n4.nabble.com/Maven-Plugin-and-connecting-over-HTTPS-td4678814.html) the plugin will use https by default, if not http-port is set. Also you could set `forceHttps` to `true` to force the server to use https.

Also there might be some errors because of the `openejb-core` version you use in your current plugin. You may need another `openejb-core`-version if you switch the plugin.